# link looses its bg color when visited in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

In IE 10 the menu looses the bg color when it is visited. I tried to debug it but no luck till now.

Comment: What code? It is not related to javascript or anything its about CSS

Answer (score 3):

It's because IE doesn't support gradient transitions you used, just plain color. When visited, it sets the bg to the color from `a:visited`.

Comment: but I have separate style.css for IE and there I use non-gradient colors for the menu classes.

Comment: thats the only way to do it.

Comment: It's the best to just add a normal background-color to the gradient div and not a seperate file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background-color: #fff; for class="color2".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a 'default' `background-color`, so no gradient for IE10

```
.color2 {
//your gradient background-colors
background-color: red; /*IE10 fallback */
//rest of code
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work, I removed the gradient properties for color2 and tried it but it didnt work.

Comment: I just named it color2. but are your calling the navlinks with classes like color2? otherwise you have to change the class name :) I don't know how your style class is called :)